# How to publish ignored by git distribution files to Bower?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

I am building a package for NPM and Bower.

I follow this pattern to keep the working files (ES6) in the `src/` directory of my package and build my distribution files (ES5, compiled with Babel) in the `lib/` directory.

In my `.gitignore` I ignore `lib/`.

On the one hand side (NPM), I have a [`.npmignore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) which ignores `src/`, instead of `lib/`. This is how I publish the `lib/` folder contents on NPM.

On the other hand side (Bower), the `lib/` folder is missing in the repository, therefore, the Bower package doesn't include it. How can I publish the ignored by git `lib/` folder contents on Bower?

Comment: Perhaps you could have your build files in a separate branch (use some sort of CI to build, push, and tag to that branch). Only problem I see would be that your tags would have to be on that build branch, and not on master, or bower might have a problem. Although, doing that would also mean that your GitHub release downloads have exactly the built files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's not possible.

The workaround I found is to commit the distribution files in the repository.

If they really piss you off - you could do this dirty trick: commit them right before you release a tag. Release a tag. Remove them.

Or simply drop the Bower support. But that's not a *real* solution to the problem, isn't it? :-)